# Assign values in dataframe group using previous group row

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Consider the following dataframe:

```
A |  B |  C
_____________
a |  1 |  1
a |  5 |  NaN
b |  3 |  1
b |  4 |  NaN
c |  2 |  1
c |  2 |  NaN
a |  1 |  NaN
b |  3 |  NaN
c |  4 |  NaN
```

My goal is to update column C based on a rule that also includes the previous row, for each group.
Just as an example, if the value from B column is smaller than the previous one, the C should have a value of 0, otherwise keep the value from the previous C.

So this would give me the following:

```
A |  B |  C
_____________
a |  1 |  1
a |  5 |  1
b |  3 |  1
b |  4 |  1
c |  2 |  1
c |  2 |  1
a |  1 |  0
b |  3 |  0
c |  4 |  1
```

I was thinking of using a kind of

```
df.groupby(A).apply(lambda x: x['C'].shift(1) if x['B'].shift(1) >= x['B'] else 0)
```

but obviously this does not work as apply cannot access former rows ( I think)

If all fails, I would build individual DF's from each group and modify them individually, so not to include another group's rows in the result, but I believe there must be a more elegant solution using the original dataframe.

Any suggestions?

Comment: keep the value from the previous C means 4 ( the last row) should be 0. what's the reason for it being 1?

Comment: @sammywemmy, in my example, for the last row, the B value is 4, and because the last row relates to the "c" group, it is bigger than the last B value for that group so we keep the value of 1 for C, which is the last one. If the value of B was 1, the C columnd would have had, in that case, a value of 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try:**

```
import numpy as np
def fill(x):
    x['C'] = x['C'].fillna(method='ffill')
    x['C'] = np.where(x['B'].values <= x['B'].shift(1).values, 0, x['C'])
    return x
df = df.groupby('A').apply(fill)
```

Here, the idea is to 1st fill the NAN values with the previous value then replace the value with 0 if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: thanks for the np.where solution, i never used it before. I am still getting some weird result on my actual data, as some nan's appear after applying the function, even if I ffill before like you suggested. I will check and see where the problem is

Comment: np.where is super fast if you wanna perform some if-else condition.

Comment: i'm gonna mark your answer as correct, but for my actual dataset it didn't work as I don't think I managed to put everything in context in one question. But it's a start. Thanks